# Using the resulting AMI from an image builder recipe using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform resource for a `aws_imagebuilder_image` with the proper image recipe and infrastructure configuration working to create an AMI.

I want to take that resulting AMI and launch an EC2 instance with Terraform but I am seemingly unable to grab the AMI name (for example `ami-0ffd8e4d9e7353516`) coming out of my image pipeline to feed it into the `aws_instance` resource.

I tried using a data source but was unsuccessful because the data source is querying immediately when terraform is applying and not waiting for the image to be produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a data source because Terraform requires anything you query for the data source to exist at the time you run Terraform. Data sources are only for looking up things that already exist, not for things that will exist after `terraform apply` has run.

Looking at [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/imagebuilder_image) you should reference the `output_resources` attribute, I believe that would look like this:

```
ami_name = tolist(aws_imagebuilder_image.your_resource_name.output_resources[0].amis)[0].name
```

or:

```
ami_id = tolist(aws_imagebuilder_image.your_resource_name.output_resources[0].amis)[0].image
```

---

You would have to cast `amis` to a list before you can reference an individual AMI, because `amis` is a set.

Comment: That worked correctly, thanks ! What threw me off originally is that VSCode shows incorrect completions for that line so I thought it was invalid. But now it is applying correctly with expected results.